# Can you solve my JQuery text animation bug that is causing the wrong text to change appearance?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Our website's main index page has some text animation using a jquery plugin called textillate.  This is only supposed to affect the larger tagline text in the upper part of the page.  However, it is causing the blocks of text along the bottom of the page to "blink" between two different font appearances.  As an example, you can look at the block of text that starts with "Agile methodology ...".

For me, this issue occurs in Safari but not Chrome.

Here is the website:  [www.clearsoftinc.com/index.html](http://www.clearsoftinc.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the .body-content a CSS transform that does nothing. Like so:
    .body-content {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
This will force the browser to use the GPU (instead of the CPU) to render your .body-content.